# Qual a melhor forma de compartilhar variáveis entre 3 Activity's?

Tags: android

Tenho as variáveis:

```
photo_path
audio_path
commentary
```

E gostaria de que as activities TextoActivity, EnviarAlertaActivity e AudioActivity compartilhassem essas variáveis e elas mantivessem o mesmo valor independente de quantas trocas de tela eu fizesse.

Tentei fazer isso utilizando Intent e na hora de trocar de tela passava as variáveis por via putExtra(), mas fica muito difícil de dar manutenção.

Quais são as outras formas?

Comment: Borda, além de passar dados pela `Intent`, você pode utilizar `SharedPreferences` se forem dados de configuração. A Idéia do Cícero é muito boa, mas eu recomendo usar variáveis de instância e criar um `Singleton` (desacolando no `onDestroy`) para evitar Memory Leaks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode criar uma sessão:

```
public class App extends Application{


   public static String photo_path;
   public static String audio_path;
   public static String commentary;

}
```

E acessar em qualquer das acitvitys.

Coloque isso no AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        **android:name=".App"**
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
```

Você também pode salvar em arquivo de preferências o valor das variáveis quando usar get e set.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar o metodo acima citado pelo @Cicero Moura de criar uma Application propria, ou pode criar objetos usando o padrão singleton, ou juntar as duas soluçoes que considero a melhor opção, pois você ira padronizar e organizar melhor sua aplicação, com isso seu código ficara mais fácil de dar manutenção.

```
public class Singleton {

    private static Singleton uniqueInstance;

    private Singleton() {
    }

    public static synchronized Singleton getInstance() {
        if (uniqueInstance == null)
            uniqueInstance = new Singleton();
        return uniqueInstance;
    }
}
```

Comment: Boa! =) hehehehe

Answer (score 1):

Uma prática que utilizo bastante em meus projetos é criar classes `Uteis` para centralizar todos os `result_code` e mensagens entre `Activity`

Um exemplo

```
public class Prefs {
    public static final String PHOTO_PATH = "photo_path";
    public static final String AUDIO_PATH = "audio_path";
    public static final String COMMENTARY = "commentary";
}
```

Agora, enviando para sua `Activity` via intent e recebendo em outra `Activity`:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, SuaActivity.class);
intent.putExtra(Prefs.PHOTO_PATH , photo_path);
intent.putExtra(Prefs.AUDIO_PATH , audio_path);
intent.putExtra(Prefs.COMMENTARY , commentary);
startActivity(intent);
...
if (getIntent().getExtras() != null) {
    String photo_path= getIntent().getExtras().getString(Prefs.PHOTO_PATH, "");
    String audio_path = getIntent().getExtras().getString(Prefs.AUDIO_PATH, "");  
    String commentary = getIntent().getExtras().getString(Prefs.COMMENTARY, "");  
}
```

Você pode fazer isso também para centralizar os `reques_code` no `startActivityForResult`, por exemplo:

```
public class RequestCode{
    public static final int UMA_ACAO = 0;
    public static final int OUTRA_ACAO = 1;
    public static final int MAIS_UMA_ACAO = 2;
}
```

E na sua `Activity`

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, SuaActivity.class);
intent.putExtra(Prefs.PHOTO_PATH , photo_path);
intent.putExtra(Prefs.AUDIO_PATH , audio_path);
intent.putExtra(Prefs.COMMENTARY , commentary);
startActivityForResult(intent, RequestCode.UMA_ACAO );    
    ...      
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (requestCode == RequestCode.UMA_ACAO)
         //fazer algo
    else if (requestCode == RequestCode.OUTRA_ACAO)
         //fazer algo
    else if (requestCode == RequestCode.MAIS_UMA_ACAO)
         //fazer algo

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```